# Ponderosa suddenly out of the prime rib in the middle of the buffet line

Tags: cultural-phrases

In [this article](https://www.theguardian.com/media/2022/feb/22/neil-cavuto-fox-news-business-covid-vaccination-death-threats) about a news anchor's nearly dying of covid, he described the experience as very scare with this phrase:

> Ponderosa suddenly out of the prime rib in the middle of the buffet line scary.

I am probably missing some cultural references here, because I don't understand this sentence at all.

Comment: It's a creative metaphor (or perhaps a creative proportionality; either way, a creative analogy). Non-standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ponderosa is the name of a restaurant chain. [They pride themselves on their prime rib](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTb2Or-Gj9k)` (a specific cut of beef). When many people come to a buffet, they form a line, and if the speciality most people came for runs out while people are still queuing, that may lead to some very dissatisfied customers.

I would guess that the anchor either worked in the hospitality industry before, or reported on [some brawl that broke out because of something like this](https://www.clickorlando.com/news/local/2022/02/01/video-massive-fight-breaks-out-at-golden-corral-over-piece-of-meat/), and thus felt there was a similarly life-threatening quality about this... or it was meant to (jokingly?) downplay the threat of Cov19.

The sentence might get more palatable if you remove one 'the':

"Ponderosa suddenly out of prime rib in the middle of the buffet line"

Comment: As a Brit I'd never come across the restaurant chain and could only relate the name to what I imagine is the original, that is the ranch in the old TV series Bonanza. I think a more universal metaphor would have been "Macdonald's out of burgers scary". Still vastly inflating the significance of the catering emergency but expressing the unexpected and unthinkable nature of the event.